# Force a SAVE in every subroutine using gfortran

Tags: fortran, fortran77

We have a big software package written time ago in Fortran 77 using a Compaq compiler that assumed a SAVE in every subroutine, so no subroutine has a explicit SAVE in the code.

Now I had to reuse and modify it to make it work in Linux with gfortran. Gfortran is in fact a f90 compiler but it worked with just some minimum changes and some additional flags. However I'm having problems with the missing SAVE statements. Some COMMON structures are not SAVEd, some are, and it seems to depend on the platform (Windows/Linux) and gfortran version.

I've tried the flag -fno-automatic, but some COMMON blocks are still unsaved, as the man page says, the -fno-automatic doesn't affect the COMMON blocks.

Any idea how can I force a SAVE in every subroutine using gfortran? I'd like to avoid modifying every subroutine.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to use -fno-automatic compiler option and a save statement with the names of all the named common blocks.  See ["Saving" a common block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9423028/saving-a-common-block)

Comment: Thanks, but that's precisely what I want to avoid, modifying the legacy code. I could just add "SAVE" to every subroutine but I would prefer another solution.

Comment: You don't need to add SAVE to every subroutine.  I think just once per named common block.

Comment: That would be great, I could write a dummy function with all the commons saved. However it seems that you must SAVE all COMMON blocks in all subroutines. But when searching about what you said, I found a very interesting comment: if a COMMON block is defined in the main function (the program itself), it will remain defined and common automatically for all subroutines, so I could include all COMMONs in the main program. Not the best solution but may be the fastest.

Comment: That is clear from the linked question.   A named COMMON is allowed to lose its values if it goes out of scope.   So if it is referenced from the main program or in the call tree in such a way that some caller is in action from the from to last use of the COMMON, then the values will be persistent.

Answer (score 0):

try the compiling option -fno-automatic

Comment: Thanks! But -fno-automatic doesn't apply to COMMON blocks :(