# COMMON block shared variables

Tags: fortran, fortran-common-block

Let's say I have two subroutines

```
  SUBROUTINE S2909                                                    
  COMMON X,Y
  X =2;
  Y =3;
  END

  SUBROUTINE S2900                                                    
  COMMON X,Y
   //display X and Y 
  END
```

A COMMON block is used for sharing variables so does this mean if the value of `X`, `Y` that is updated in the subroutine `S2909` will be same as in subroutine `S2900`?

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, yes, the variables are shared throughout the program. Their values will depend on the order with which the subroutines are called.

The following program

```
program test
real x,y
common x,y

x = 1
y = 2

write(*,*) x,y
call changevals
write(*,*) x,y

end program test


subroutine changevals
real x,y
common x,y

x = 12
y = 13

end subroutine changevals
```

outputs

```
1.00000 2.00000
12.00000 13.00000
```

Answer (score 1):

This sharing is indeed the point of common blocks.  In particular, the `common` statement allows so-called *storage association* between various entities throughout a program.

So, the entities `X` and `Y` in the subroutine `S2909` are storage associated with the entities `X` and `Y` in the subroutine `S2900`.  Changes to the value in one entity `X` are reflected by the other entity `X`.

There are a few things worth noting about this, though.

In the `common` statements of the question this is relying on what is known as *blank common*.  This is what happens when there is no name specified for a common block, such as in the statement

```
common /named/ x, y
```

This is noteworthy because attempting to generalize the behaviour in this question to [named common blocks may be troublesome](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9423028).

The entities in the various places where the common blocks are referenced are associated not by name, but by order in the storage sequence.  This means that care must be made with say

```
SUBROUTINE S2909
COMMON X,Y
END

SUBROUTINE S2900
COMMON Y,X
END
```

But my answer really has two points to make, and the above was just a preamble to make it more answer-like.

First, I'll mention a pathological case which I wouldn't expect to see in the wild.

The question is relying on implicit typing.  Consider the following

```
subroutine S2909
  common x, y
  x = 2.
  y = 3.
end subroutine S2909

implicit integer (a-z)

call S2909
call S2900

contains
  subroutine S2900
    common x, y

    print*, x, y
  end subroutine
end
```

This is an example of uncivil code writing, but it illustrates an important thing.  Because the entities `x` in the `S2909` and `x` in the subroutine `S2900` are of different types defining one of them causes the other to become undefined.  That is: updating the value of one doesn't update the value of the other.  With explicit typing one could see the same thing, or if there was implicit typing with default rules and entities `i` and `j`, say, in one subroutine.

And the final thing I want to say is: there are [much better ways of sharing data "globally" without common blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32386146).